# ClearCase Integration with Visual Studio

Tags: visual-studio-2008, clearcase, source-control-bindings

I'm trying to open a project source controlled by IBM ClearCase, but it gives this message to me:

```
The project '[MyProject]' is under source control. 
An error occurred registering this project with source control. 
It is recommended that you do not make any changes to this project.
```

I just don't know what to do. I've already re-installed everything. The Visual Studio integration is already installed, but it keeps giving error messages.

Is anyone knows a solution for this?

Answer: I get a solution. I just selected the ClearCase in Tools -> SourceControl

Answer (score 1):

The [IBM Technote swg21267165](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg21267165) mentions:

[image: error occurred registering this project with source control]

> **Errors and Warnings about ClearCase and VS.NET integration using VSIP bindings**
>
> This issue is seen if the integration between ClearCase and VS .NET is broken or if the solution file and projects were not converted properly to use VSIP bindings if the solution file and projects were developed in a previous integration of ClearCase and VS .NET.
>
> The bindings and source control information referencing each project associated to a specific solution do not contain the same information for the correct source code control provider.

So carefully check your solution file and your project file (`.csproj`, `.vcproj`, ...) following the recommendations of this IBM technote.

> 1. Verify that ClearCase and VS .NET are integrated correctly using the indicators mentioned above.
> 2. If the two applications are not integrated correctly, then follow the procedure in [technote 1259189](http://www-1.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg21259189) on how to integrate the full ClearCase client with VS .NET 2003/2005 or [technote 1319889](http://ibm.com/support/docview.wss?rs=727&uid=swg21319889) for integrating the CCRC plug-in with VS .NET 2005.
> 3. Once the two applications have been successfully integrated then the projects must be converted to use the new VSIP bindings. Follow [technote 1254745](http://www.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?rs=984&uid=swg21254745) on how to convert projects that were created using the old MSSCCI bindings. This is necessary in order for the solution file and projects to continue to be used after an upgrade requiring the bindings to be changed to reflect a new source code control configuration.

Answer (score 1):

Please open the *.CsProject file of your project then replace bellow tag

```
<SccProjectName>SAK</SccProjectName>
<SccLocalPath>SAK</SccLocalPath>
<SccAuxPath>SAK</SccAuxPath>
<SccProvider>SAK</SccProvider>
```

With

```
<SccProjectName>
</SccProjectName>
<SccLocalPath>
</SccLocalPath>
<SccAuxPath>
</SccAuxPath>
<SccProvider>
</SccProvider>
```

close the solution, close VS, reopen VS then your problem will be resolve.